# Collect user response on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I am creating a GitHub pages website and I want to collect a few responses from the users and store them in a file to my GitHub repository (I'll be adding user authentication so not everyone can access it and submit responses) or elsewhere.

Is it possible to have form elements and collect user data in a file? If so how would I go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Google Forms with success in the past. You simply create the form and link to it. You can view responses and even export the responses into Google Sheets, etc. Link: https://www.google.com/forms/about/